How to make snap scrollable chart like an apple health?

I want to create a chart similar to the orange-colored chart in the GIF which is in Apple Health App with snap-scroll capabilities at both day and week levels,
but I'm not sure how to approach it. Is there are some examples and How can I make it? Thank you.

I have an idea you can give it a try. You can listen to the scroll event and scroll the chart exactly by day or week. Example: if one day have a bar chart with width of 16px, if you want to snap by day, you scroll -16px, if you want to scroll by week, multiply the scroll value with 7
